# How to sign in with Firebase Auth using python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to make an app and I can't figure out how to sign in to a user with the python library firebase_admin. I don't have any code as of this moment. Let me know if you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK is designed to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. It gets its authorization from its context or from a credentials file that you provide to it, and which gives it full, administrative access to the project. Therefor it doesn't need, and doesn't have a way, to sign in as a specific user.

If your use-case requires that you sign a user in to Firebase from your Python code, you *can* consider calling the [REST API to authenticate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth). But the use-case for this would typically be to then pass the ID token you receive back to a user (similar to the use-case in [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)).